# Select(HTML) com múltipla seleção. Marco uma e deveria marcar todas, não está funcionando

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Tenho esse select com multiplos select

```
<tr>
                                <td width="10%" class="label_right">Autorização Prévia: &nbsp;</td>
                                <td class="label_left">
                                    <select id="ddl_autorizacaoprevia" multiple>
                                        <option value="0">TODAS AS AUTORIZAÇÕES</option>
                                        <option value="T">TÉCNICA / ADMINISTRATIVA</option>
                                        <option value="A">SISTÊMICA</option>
                                        <option value="N">NÃO PRECISA</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
```

O que desejo é que quando eu selecionar "**TODAS AS AUTORIZAÇÕES**", todas as outras deveriam ser selecionadas e quando eu clicar em qualquer outra, todas as selecionadas deveriam ser desmarcadas e apenas a selecionada deveria estar marcada(selecionada). Realmente não sei como fazer isso. Estou procurando na internet, mas até agora não achei nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com jquery seria algo assim:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#ddl_autorizacaoprevia option').click(function(){
       var that = $(this);
       if ($(that).val() == 0){
          $('#ddl_autorizacaoprevia option').each(function(){
             $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
          });
       }  else  {
          $('#ddl_autorizacaoprevia option').each(function(){
             $(this).removeAttr('selected'); 
          });
          $(that).attr('selected', 'selected');
       }

   }

});
```

Algo nessa linha deve resolver seu problema

Comment: Thiesen, o que é `optSelected`?

Comment: Troquei o optSelected por option.Selected, mas dá esse erro: `Uncaught ReferenceError: option is not defined`. Preciso de algum include?

Comment: Editei ali, na verdade voce tem que pegar o cara que recebeu o click

Comment: Sim, fiz isso e marca todos, mas não consigo marcar apenas um. Eu seleciono, por exemplo e quando eu clico em uma opção, não fica selecionada.

Comment: Resolvi. `that.attr('selected', 'selected');` ao invés de `$(that).attr('selected');`

Comment: Há um problema. Não funciona no IE e o browser que tem que funcionar é o IE. No Chrome funciona bem.

Comment: JQuery é cross browser, deve ser uma versão antiga do IE...

Comment: Versão 11.0.24. É nova o meu IE. Não vai nem com reza brava. Com F12, dá um erro de: Erro não especificado.

Comment: IE é sempre um problema amigo, não importa a versão kkk

Comment: Essa porra é uma desgraça.